# Mongoose.js Never Save Field Via Set

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

Is there any way to mark a field as NOT modified in mongoose?

I have a mongoose schema:

```
var schema = mongoose.Schema({
    field          : { type : String   }
  , fieldGenerated : { type : [String] }
});
```

I want to make it so that `fieldGenerated` NEVER gets set via `model.set( ... )`.

The only way it should be set is in the pre-save middleware:

```
schema.pre( 'save', function( next ) {

    // Any way to mark fieldGenerated as NOT modified here?

    // I only want to set fieldGenerated if field was set.
    // I don't want fieldGenerated to be set any other way.
    if ( this.field && this.isModified( 'field' ) ) {
        this.fieldGenerated = this.field.split( ' ' );
        this.markModified( 'fieldGenerated' );
    }

    next();
}
```

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Not directly, but how about if you just regenerate the field if it's been modified:

```
schema.pre( 'save', function( next ) {
    if ( this.field && ( this.isModified( 'field' ) || this.isModified( 'fieldGenerated' ) ) {
        this.fieldGenerated = this.field.split( ' ' );
    }
    next();
}
```

Comment: This is a good workaround but it requires additional processing to regenerate the field when it isn't necessary.  If generating the field isn't cheap, this won't be acceptable.